# iPhone app Button style like "add to homescreen" button

Tags: iphone, button, uibutton

i'm new in iphone app developing,
and i just wanted to create a buttonbar like this on the left screenshot.

http://www.internet-fuer-architekten.de/files/iphone_app-simulation2.png

What kind of buttons are these?

The only buttons i can find in xcode are the "Round Rect buttons" and the "Toolbar Buttons". But both of them do differ to the buttons on the screenshot.

I saw this Buttons in many apps on my iPhone, so i thought they must be Buttons from IOS.

Does anybody know, how to get this buttons?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: I dislike the fact that the screenshot link is no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left screenshot shows an [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use this class to make similar action sheet popups, but if you'd like to use that button style outside of an `UIActionSheet` class, you'll have to create a custom `UIButton` with background image.